# How do I delete a page from a PDF in Okular?

Tags: pdf, okular

Didn't see an option in the menus or any documentation on what I imagine is something simple:

I have a multi-page PDF and want to delete a specific page within Okular's GUI.

Comment: can you elaborate on your issue?

Comment: I'm afraid it's that simple

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the pdf file completely or hide it in Okular?

Comment: to modify the multi-page PDF to remove a specific page within the PDF, using Okular's GUI

Comment: I do not think you can with Okukar. Master PDF editor would be a much better option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way to remove a page in Okular. However, it can refresh
modified PDF document automatically so there is no need to re-open the
document manually after modifying it in external tool such as
`pdftk`. To remove a given page use `cat` option and specify a range
of pages you'd like to keep in the target PDF file. For example, if
you want to remove 5th page in `document.pdf` execute the following
command:

```
pdftk document.pdf cat 1-4 6-end output out.pdf && mv out.pdf document.pdf
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want an easy GUI solution, I have found **PDF Arranger** to be really valuable and end user compatible.
With it you can merge, join, split, extract, delete and insert single pages from PDF documents, and all using the mouse.

And it's just 300kB.

`sudo apt install pdfarranger`

Comment: Yup. This is it. Lightweight and simple. Can remove pages, re-arrange and append pdf docs. Works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

I always try to reduce the dependency-trail of my installed packages.
For `pdftk` I would have to install 16 additional Java dependencies on my  Gentoo system ...

So (at least for completeness sake) I wanted to point out, that you can use Ghostscript for this task. It is preinstalled on most Linux systems.

Let's say you want to delete page 2,7,9 and 14 of you document:

```
gs -sPageList=1,3-6,8,10-13,15- -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER  -sOutputFile=myPDF_out.pdf myPDF.pdf
```

The trailing dash after 15 indicates, that you want to keep all the pages from 15 to the end of the document.

So if you want to delete only page 5 you would issue:

```
gs -sPageList=1-4,6- -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER  -sOutputFile=myPDF_out.pdf myPDF.pdf
```

(Be aware that page numbers have to be in ascending order)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, better than any other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use LibreOffice "draw" to open the pdf file, delete the pages you want and then EXPORT it as a pdf.....done.

Comment: you can even export and select the desired page range to save one step

Answer (score 3):

LibreOffice draw didn't work for me, as it munted the formatting.  However, [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) allowed me to remove (and re-arrange) pages while preserving the original document formatting.

Comment: Thank you, this is what ultimately worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete pages from the *start* or *end* of the document, using Okular:

1. Menu `File > Print`
2. For `Name` select `Print to File (PDF)`
3. Expand `Options >>`
4. Select `Pages from [_] to [_]`
5. Increase the first number to skip pages at the start
6. Decrease the second number to skip pages at the end
7. You can keep `Output file` as the current filename, if you like. (After writing the file, Okular will reload it automatically.)
8. Hit `Print`